# Coding in a simple dash/slide mechanic C# Unity2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to achieve a simple dash akin to Megaman or more recently Hollow Knight where the user inputs a button and they are pushed forward and are unable to cancel.

I have something simple working right now but it simply teleports the player where I'm looking for a fluid motion forward. I've tried youtube tutorials and multiple searches online but I can't seem to find anything that works.

This is my code thus far

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.G) && isSliding == false) {
            slideCount += Time.deltaTime;
            isSliding = true;
            if (slideCount < maxSlideCount) {
                rb2d.AddRelativeForce (Vector2.right * 100f);
            } 
    else
                slideCount = 0;
                isSliding = false;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Would your character's `Rigidbody` happen to have a huge weight, friction or dampening force being applied to it?  This is rather common if you're building a [2D character controller](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/2d-game-creation/2d-character-controllers). You may be seeing this because it is forced right and immediately halted because the counter forces are huge, so it looks like teleportation.  `AddRelativeForce` call looks correct.

Comment: What is the character standing on? If you change it to an up vector, do you see the character leave the ground?

Comment: This is currently what they're standing on [platform](http://prntscr.com/lvxhlg) If I change the GetKeyDown to GetKey it works the way I want but it continuously gives force and doesn't stop when it hits the maxSlideCount, but I want it to work like a one press = the full dash and not just a constant force

Comment: You'll want to specify `ForceMode.Impulse` as the second argument to the force add.

Comment: So something like this?

```if (slideCount < maxSlideCount) {
    rb2d.AddRelativeForce (Vector2.right * 0.05f, ForceMode.Impulse);```

Comment: Okay, I added that and made it work however the character is still teleporting

Comment: Teleporting aside for a second, the conditional logic is `if (g down && !sliding) {sliding=true} else { sliding = false }`. If `g down = true` by continually holding the key down, then `sliding` will toggle true to false rapidly.

Comment: Yeah, with this logic I have to press the key multiple times to get a significant output, which leads into teleportation. Is there a way to apply this force over time?

Comment: Depends on how you want the mechanic to work. Do you want the character to have constant velocity during the slide? What happens if the character runs into other objects, should the character slow or stop?  The most basic version is the impulse force with a correct magnitude like you have - adjust the multiplier until a single burst gets your character where you want.

Comment: I want the character to have constant velocity during the slide, where it's a set distance and cannot be cancelled. So you get the same result everytime. In terms of collisions and walls, I'd like the character to be stopped when they collide with said object

Comment: Rigidbody.velocity code sample should help  (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html)

Comment: I'll have a little more of a look into it, can't seem to get it right